# mvn:perform does not pull the providerImplementations

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin, jgit

I am using the maven release plugin with git over https, trying to use the jgit provider.

pom.xml

```xml
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-scm-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
            <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-scm-provider-jgit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
            <tagNameFormat>r@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-scm-provider-jgit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
...
```

This is how I run prepare:

```
mvn -X release:prepare -Dusername=whatever -Dpassword=whatever
```

This works fine, here an excerpt from the command output:

```
...
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Aggregating
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <addSchema default-value="true">${addSchema}</addSchema>
  <allowReleasePluginSnapshot default-value="false">${allowReleasePluginSnapshot}</allowReleasePluginSnapshot>
  <allowTimestampedSnapshots default-value="false">${ignoreSnapshots}</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
  <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
  <autoVersionSubmodules default-value="false">${autoVersionSubmodules}</autoVersionSubmodules>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <checkModificationExcludeList>${checkModificationExcludeList}</checkModificationExcludeList>
  <commitByProject default-value="false">${commitByProject}</commitByProject>
  <completionGoals default-value="">${completionGoals}</completionGoals>
  <developmentVersion>${developmentVersion}</developmentVersion>
  <dryRun default-value="false">${dryRun}</dryRun>
  <generateReleasePoms default-value="false">${generateReleasePoms}</generateReleasePoms>
  <javaHome default-value="${java.home}"/>
  <localRepoDirectory default-value="${maven.repo.local}"/>
  <mavenExecutorId default-value="invoker">${mavenExecutorId}</mavenExecutorId>
  <mavenHome default-value="${maven.home}"/>
  <password>${password}</password>
  <pomFileName>${pomFileName}</pomFileName>
  <preparationGoals default-value="clean verify">${preparationGoals}</preparationGoals>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <projectVersionPolicyId default-value="default">${projectVersionPolicyId}</projectVersionPolicyId>
  <providerImplementations>
    <tagNameFormat>r@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    <git>jgit</git>
  </providerImplementations>
  <pushChanges default-value="true">${pushChanges}</pushChanges>
  <reactorProjects default-value="${reactorProjects}"/>
  <releaseVersion>${releaseVersion}</releaseVersion>
  <remoteTagging default-value="true">${remoteTagging}</remoteTagging>
  <resume default-value="true">${resume}</resume>
  <scmCommentPrefix default-value="[maven-release-plugin] ">${scmCommentPrefix}</scmCommentPrefix>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <settings default-value="${settings}"/>
  <suppressCommitBeforeTag default-value="false">${suppressCommitBeforeTag}</suppressCommitBeforeTag>
  <tag>${tag}</tag>
  <tagBase>${tagBase}</tagBase>
  <tagNameFormat default-value="@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}">${tagNameFormat}</tagNameFormat>
  <updateDependencies default-value="true">${updateDependencies}</updateDependencies>
  <updateWorkingCopyVersions default-value="true">${updateWorkingCopyVersions}</updateWorkingCopyVersions>
  <useEditMode default-value="false">${useEditMode}</useEditMode>
  <username>${username}</username>
  <waitBeforeTagging default-value="0">${waitBeforeTagging}</waitBeforeTagging>
</configuration>
...
```

Now I run perform:

```
mvn -X release:perform
```

And this is what maven sees:

```
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Aggregating
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <connectionUrl>${connectionUrl}</connectionUrl>
  <dryRun default-value="false">${dryRun}</dryRun>
  <goals>${goals}</goals>
  <javaHome default-value="${java.home}"/>
  <localCheckout default-value="false">${localCheckout}</localCheckout>
  <localRepoDirectory default-value="${maven.repo.local}"/>
  <mavenExecutorId default-value="invoker">${mavenExecutorId}</mavenExecutorId>
  <mavenHome default-value="${maven.home}"/>
  <password>${password}</password>
  <pomFileName>${pomFileName}</pomFileName>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <reactorProjects default-value="${reactorProjects}"/>
  <releaseProfiles>${releaseProfiles}</releaseProfiles>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <settings default-value="${settings}"/>
  <useReleaseProfile default-value="true">${useReleaseProfile}</useReleaseProfile>
  <username>${username}</username>
  <workingDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/checkout">${workingDirectory}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Obviously `providerImplementations` is not present in the second output and maven is trying to find a command line git. I would expect it to cry out for not having username and password, but when I just added the git path to the PATH it worked?!

This is windows, maven 3.0.5, java 1.7.0_55 64-bit.

I want to get it running without a command line git.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: the perform goal seems not to have those configuration options: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html - the only one related seems "localCheckout": http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#localCheckout - so not sure if this will improve things :/

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Any workaround found?

Comment: No, just ditched jgit...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the release perform goal don't support providerImplementations.

I create an issue here, and provided a patch for this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-921